# How to install javafx with VSCode on Mac

Tags: mac, visual-studio-code, macos-mojave

I am having problems using JavaFx on my Mac. I do not know how to get VSCode to recognize JavaFx libraries, let alone know which libraries to download for JavaFx. Every time I try and compile my JavaFx code I get the following error:

```
HelloWorld.java:1: error: package javafx.application does not exist
```

This error is followed by a bunch of other errors basically saying how different packages do not exist or can be found. Anyone know how I can fix this issue?